# Dianoga - JPEGTrans locking resource during deployment

Tags: dianoga

Seem to be suffering an inconsistent issue whereby jpegtrans is not completing / locking a resource during deployments despite the application being shut down. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Dianoga are you using?

Comment: It's an inherited project - 2.0.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on Dianoga 2.0.2 I would strongly recommend upgrading to the latest 3.x version. 3.x uses much safer integration methods, is more modular, uses more modern compression tools, and most importantly for your use-case is much smarter about releasing resources.